# Connected affine scheme

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am trying to find a simple algebraic proof of the fact that if the affine scheme $X$ associated to a ring $A$ is connected, then $A$ is a nontrivial product of rings.

I know that if $\mathrm{spec}\ A = U_1 \sqcup U_2$, then I can construct a section of the structure sheaf that is 1 one the first open set and 0 on the second and that gives me a nontrivial idempotent, but is there a simpler explanation that does not use the structure sheaf ? (I feel like this is overkill)

Here is what I tried: If $X$ is disconnected, then I can write $X = V(I) \sqcup V(J)$. The fact that the two closed sets are disjoint gives me $I+J = A$, therefore by the Chinese remainder theorem, I can write $A/(I \cap J) \simeq A/I \times A/J$. 
However, the fact that $X = V(I) \cup V(J)$ only gives me $I \cap J \subset \sqrt{(0)}$, therefore I only have a surjection $\phi: A \to A/I \times A/J$. I tried taking an element $x \in \phi^{-1}({(1,0)})$ and making manipulations but I am not sure how to conclude. Surely the answer is right under my nose but I don't quite see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your quotients don't give a nice direct product decomposition; you have to play around a bit to get different ideals that give you the decomposition.

So far, you have shown $I + J = 1$. Thus, $x + y = 1$ for some $x \in I$, $y \in J$. Now, since $IJ \subset \sqrt{0}$, we have $(xy)^m = 0$ for some $m$. Then, we have
$$
  1 = (x + y)^{2m} = \underbrace{x^{2m} + \cdots + \binom{2m}{m+1} x^{m+1}y^{m-1}}_{e_1} + \underbrace{\binom{2m}{m}x^my^m + \cdots + y^{2m}}_{e_2}
$$
and these elements $e_1,e_2$ satisfy the relations
$$e_1e_2 = 0, \quad e_1^2 = e_1, \quad e_2^2 = e_2.$$
You can then prove $A \cong A/(e_1) \times A/(e_2)$.

Comment: Could you explain how to prove the injectivity of the map $A\rightarrow A/(e_1)\times A/(e_2)$? Thanks!